# ¿Modal dinámico en Angular + Bootstrap?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de crear un modal para cada uno de los datos enviados en el siguiente ciclo:

```
 <tbody class="font-size-base">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of contacto | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
                  <td>
                    {{item.cliente}}
                  <td>
                    {{item.correo}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{item.telefono}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + item._id">
                  Launch demo modal
                </button>
                  </td>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="{{item._id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

Sin embargo, aunque el botón que ejecuta el modal y el modal, terminan recibiendo la misma id:

*Botón para ejecutar el modal con el atributo data-target:*

```
<button _ngcontent-eoq-c127="" type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary"
 data-target="#62dee4261fa4460bf07a6e6e"> Launch demo modal </button>
```

*Contenido del modal con el id igual al data target mencionado:*

```
<div _ngcontent-eoq-c127="" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="62dee4261fa4460bf07a6e6e">
```

**El modal directamente NO se abre, NO ejecuta en absoluto:**

¿Qué podría ser? Por qué mi modal no se abre? He revisado bien las librerías e intentar abrirlo cambiando el datatarget y el ID por palabras simples como "Modal" y en ese caso funciona a la perfección ¡¿Que está mal?!

Comment: yo tube esta necesidad en hace mucho tiempo en BS3 y hay dos caminos:

Comment: A) crea una plantilla y cada vez que necesites un modal dinamico le pasas los datos: titulo, contenido, botones, id, incluso el Z-index si quieres que se vea sobre otro modal

Comment: B) Armar todo el html del Modal incluyendo los datos que te mencione anteriormente y agregandolo al DOM...

Comment: ***No existe algo ya listo para usar...***

Comment: Esta linkeado el script de bootstrap que permite hacer esas interacciones? (aunque no creo que sea una buena práctica ya que estás usando Angular, en teoría deberías mostrar el modal con Angular)

Comment: Si está bien likeado el script, como menciono todo funciona cuando le cambio el ID y el datatarget por palabras simples como "Modal" o "ExampleModal", etc. Pero cuando agrego un ID que viene de una base de datos en su lugar, todo falla

Comment: @MauroAguilar no le va a funcionar por que estoy casi seguro que el boton y el modal fueron agregados por ajax y no pertenecen al DOM original...

Comment: @JhoanS.Londoño confirma si el modal y el boton lo estas agregando por ajax o algun metodo que no exista cuando carga la pagina???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado utilizar el modal a modo de componente? me parece una mejor práctica que la manera en la que estas tratando de hacerlo ya que estas usando Angular, [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qu9vj9) puedes ver como funcionaría.

Estas son las partes claves para que te funcione.

Creas un modal component aparte:

```
<!-- modal.component.html -->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{ data.title }}</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
          (click)="onCloseModal()"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{ data.content }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          (click)="onCloseModal()"
        >
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCloseModal()">
          Save changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La clase `.modal` viene `display: none;` por defecto así que con CSS la sobrescribes para que se muestre:

```
// modal.component.css
.modal {
  display: block;
}
```

La lógica del componente es sencilla; recibe el input `data` para mostrar la información dinámica que le pases y emite el evento `closeModal` cuando le das a alguno de los botones para cerrar:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter();

  onCloseModal(): void {
    this.closeModal.emit();
  }
}
```

Para utilizarla simplemente la muestras con un `ngIf`:

```
...
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
      <td><a class="link" (click)="setSelectedItem(item)">Open</a></td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>

<!-- muestre el modal siempre y cuando haya un selectedItem: -->
<app-modal
  *ngIf="selectedItem"
  [data]="selectedItem"
  (closeModal)="setSelectedItem(null)"
></app-modal>
```

Esta es la lógica del componente que la usa:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [...];
  selectedItem = null;

  setSelectedItem(item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
  }
}
```

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! Ha funcionado estupendo en mi programa. Agregué un background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5) !important; al modal debido a que como es un modal en visibilidad block, no utiliza el background que le colocaba bootstrap.